# What if the stationary mass of fundamental particular were different?

Tags: standard-model

My question is the following:

Consider the possibility of existing variations of the elementary particles whose stationary mass were 100 times smaller. I mean, electrons and other fundamental particles  with 1/100 (or 1/1000) the stationary mass they have. All other things remaining equal, my questions are:

- Such particles would be able to form atoms?
- Said atoms could form molecules and macroscopic bodies?
- Which different properties would we expect that such bodies could have? They obviously would be much lighter, but would they interact with light differently? Would we be able to see them? Would we be able to touch and feel them?
- Such particles would enable the existence of stable elements with higher atomic numbers, like stable versions of low half-life elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose by *stationary mass* you mean what is usually called
*rest mass* or [*invariant mass*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_mass).

So let us assume the rest masses of all elementary particles
(electrons, quarks, ...) are $100$
times smaller than they are in our universe.

> Such particles would be able to form atoms?

Yes, because the [electromagnetic interaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetism) between charges
is still there. But according to quantum mechanics
the atoms would be $100$ times larger.

> Said atoms could form molecules and macroscopic bodies?

Yes, but the molecules and macroscopic bodies
would also be $100$ times larger, because they are
governed by the electromagnetic interaction as well.

> Which different properties would we expect that such bodies
> could have? They obviously would be much lighter, but would
> they interact with light differently? Would we be able to see
> them? Would we be able to touch and feel them?

The atomic and molecular binding energies
would be $100$ times smaller.
Therefore the energy of photons emitted/absorbed by
atoms and molecules would also be $100$ times smaller.
And hence the light frequencies would be $100$ times smaller
and the light wavelengths would be $100$ times larger.

So the world experienced by us would be essentially the
same, just scaled differently.

> Such particles would enable the existence of stable elements
> with higher atomic numbers, like stable versions of low half-life elements?

No, because nuclear physics is mostly governed by
the [strong interaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_interaction#Strong_interaction) and to a lesser extent by the electromagnetic
and weak interaction. The smmall rest masses of the [quarks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quark)
(which build the protons and neutrons) don't have much effect.
So protons, neutrons and hence the nuclei would still have the same
mass, size and binding energies as in our universe.